# Injecting a Transactional Grails Service into a Quartz Plugin Job gives BeanCreationExecption

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Grails version: 2.3.5
Quartz plugin version: 1.0.2

I am creating a internal Grails Plugin. This plugin has a dependency on the Grails Quartz Plugin.

I have a Grails Service: OrchestratorJobExecutorService

```
public class OrchestratorJobExecutorService {
    def grailsApplication
    def jobManagerService

    public void execute() {
        //do a bunch of stuff using here 
        //using grailsApplication to find a bunch of artifacts I've created in this plugin
        //using jobManagerService to check if trigger exists, then re/schedule job as needed
    }
}
```

I have a Quartz Job: OrchestratorJob

```
public class OrchestratorJob {
    def orchestratorJobExecutorService
    static triggers = {cron cronExpression: "0 0 15 * * ? *"}
    def group = "orchestrator"
    public execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        orchestratorJobExecutorService.execute()
    }
}
```

When this job executes I get a org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

```
....core.ErrorLogger An error occured instantiating job to be executed. job= 'myPlugin.com.bgc.OrchestratorJob'
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job instantiation failed [See nested exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.bgc.TamiOrchestratorJob': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myPluginOrchestratorJobExecutorService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:127)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:375)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.bgc.OrchestratorJob': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myPluginOrchestratorJobExecutorService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory.createJobInstance(GrailsJobFactory.java:48)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myPluginOrchestratorJobExecutorService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    ... 3 more
```

I don't have much special in myPluginGrailsPlugin.groovy file. The few lines I've changed besides the basic plugin version/description/documentation lines are:

```
def loadAfter = ['controllers','services','spring-security-core','quartz','myOtherPlugin']
def pluginExcludes = [/*a bunch of folders with files I use to test and run my plugin*/]
```

I don't have anything else defined in any of the doWith* closures or the on* closures

If I add `static transactional = false` to my OrchestratorJobExecutorService, the error goes away. I have several jobs and services and I've had to go through my entire plugin and set every service to be non-transactional. I don't really feel comfortable with that, moving away from a transactional service scares me. In the main application where this plugin is going to be used, there is going to be a lot of database interaction in some plugin artefacts I've created.

Anyone know how I can keep my services transactional and still have them be injected?

=====Edit 10/20/2014=====

Added hibernate 3 dependency:

```
runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"
```

New error:

```
context.GrailsContextLoader Error initializing the application: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.needsRefresh(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InjectionMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.needsRefresh(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InjectionMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;)Z
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Running `clean-all` and `refresh-dependencies` several times didn't seem to resolve the error (that's my standard procedure when I get errors I can't make sense of).

**BuildConfig.groovy**

```
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"

grails.release.scm.enabled = false

grails.project.repos.snapshotArtifactory.url = "https://<mySnapshotRepoUrl>"
grails.project.repos.releaseArtifactory.url = "http://<myReleaseRepoUrl>"
grails.project.repos.snapshotArtifactory.username = "<topSecretUsername>"
grails.project.repos.snapshotArtifactory.password = '<topSecretPassword>'

grails.project.fork.test = false
grails.project.fork = [
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") {}

    log "warn"

    repositories {
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenRepo ("https://<mySnapshotRepoUrl>"){updatePolicy "always"}
    }

    dependencies {
        compile("org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3")
    }

    plugins {
        build ":release:3.0.1"
        build (":tomcat:7.0.50"){export=false}
        compile "com.<myCompany>.plugins:myOtherPlugin:0.1-SNAPSHOT"
        compile ":quartz:1.0.2"
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.17"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Hibernate plugin installed, or another GORM plugin? I would think you wouldn't have gotten this far if not, but that's where the `transactionManager` bean comes from.

Comment: Burt, I do not have hibernate installed for this plugin. I don't have any domains and for my plugin, I don't need any persistence, I'm okay with Quartz just doing the in-memory store. Where my plugin is going to be consumed, it does need that persistence and will have hibernate plugin installed.
Now that you mention it, I think I came across some site that suggested I install the Hibernate plugin. I don't remember the results of that, but I'll try again and see what happens.

Comment: I am way out of my depth here, so I don't quite know what to look for. Hopefully I can provide the right info to get some help in resolving this.
I added a hibernate 3 dependency and edited post with the results.